# Bias of expected binomial reciprocal

Tags: statistics, inequality, probability-distributions

$X$ ~ Bionomial$(n, p)$. I want to evaluate the bias of $E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)$,assuming $X>0$ (excluding the probability $(1-p)^n$), that is, the difference between $E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{np}$. Based on Jensen's inequality, we have $E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) \ge \frac{1}{E(X)}$. Someone suggested me to calculate the bias based on Jensen's inequality formula. Can anyone give me some clue about how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $X$ can take the value 0, the expected value of $1/X$ is infinite. Are you sure this is exactly the question you want to ask?

Comment: What does the patch "assuming X>0" (soon forgotten when you write something like E(1/X)) mean? Is it E(X;X>0) or E(X|X>0)?

Comment: It is $E(X|X>0). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Byron noted in the comment above, the expected value will be infinite. This is due to the positive probability of X being 0. Since the expected value formula for a discrete rv is $\sum x_ip_i$, the value $\frac{1}{0}$ has a nonzero probability and hence the sum becomes infinite.

Comment: Thank Byron and Eupraxis1981 for reminding me that we should consider only positive X, that is, consider the case we have X>0.

Comment: @user127508 in that case, $E[X]$ will no longer be $np$, since you have removed X=0. What is the motivation for wanting $E[1/X|X>0]$?

Comment: I'm working on a logistic regression model with a small sample size, say a $2 \times 2$ table with small margins (assuming no 0 margin). When we inverse the observed information matrix and take expectation, there will be $E(1/X|X>0)$ in each element of covariance matrix (where X is one of row margins). I just want to compare this expected covariance with theoretical results. Please let me know if need clarification. thanks.

Comment: @user127508 ok, then take the formula I gave in my post, but start it at $x_1=1$ and divide by $1-Binom(0;n,p)$ to get the conditional probabilty, P(X=i|X>0). Jensen's inequality only states which will be bigger, it doesn't give you the value.

Comment: Thanks, Eupraxis1981. I did try to use an expansion based on an literature, say $$ \frac{1}{(1-p)^N} \sum_{i=1}^n C_i^n  p^i (1-p)^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} $$ where $C_i^n$ is the binomial coefficient. But a professor does not agree with that. He said Jensen's ineq is the way. But Jensen's ineq can only give us the lower bound, I think.

Comment: @user127508 yes, only the lower bound. You still need to calculate the proper expected value though: it won't be $np$ but $\frac{np}{1-Binom(0;n,p)}$ to get the correct conditional expected value $E[X|X>0]$.